# multithreading for simultaneous folder watching

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4

Currently I am trying to have 2 buttons that will run (nearly) simultaneously. Problem is with the below code, each button functions fine on it's own, but when both are checked only the first one runs.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt.QtCore import *
import os
import time
import traceback

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs


    @pyqtSlot
    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value,  
                                    traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        path =  "Paths to watch"
        path2 = "Paths to watch"

        self.b = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.b.setCheckable(True)
        self.b.pressed.connect(lambda: self.watcher(path))

        self.b2 = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.b2.setCheckable(True)
        self.b2.pressed.connect(lambda: self.watcher(path2))

        layout.addWidget(self.b)
        layout.addWidget(self.b2)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

    def watcher(self, s):
        worker = Worker(self.monitor(s))
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def monitor(self, s):
        before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(s)])
        while 1:
            QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(s)])
            added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
            removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
            if added: print "Added: ", ", ".join(added)
            if removed: print "Deleted: ", ", ".join(removed)
            before = after

app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Not sure if I need to assign threads, or if I can somehow have the functions update the GUI with a timer every x seconds.. or how to implement that

Comment: Parallel processing is different to multi-thread processing, both are 2 types of concurrency, but they are not the same, keep that in mind.

Comment: You have created that code ?, do you understand?

Comment: Just wrong terminology I guess. The idea is that it would at least bounce between the 2 buttons with some interval when they're both checked

Comment: My question was another, is that your code or did you get it from somewhere else? I'm telling you because I see inconsistencies in the syntax and its use.

Comment: This isn't the entirety of the code, just the portion that is in question. The watcher function is a slightly modified version of this.   http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Comment: I'm talking about the Worker class, did you create it? For example, the `signals` attribute needs to be implemented

Comment: Oh, not a chance; I'm fairly new to all this and just trying things things out until they somewhat work, then try and dissect it piece by piece

Comment: No problem, just that you must give the credit to those who made the base code, on the other hand it would help me understand that you lack your code since I see that you have missed a good part, I have patched your code and I have also pointed out the errors , check it :)

Comment: Thanks a ton, it works! Just trying to figure out how to stop it when I uncheck the button now lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have copied the code and you have not understood its operation, for example `signals` is not defined, and it is obvious that signals is an object of another class whose task is to provide the connection signals, on the other hand there is a typographical error in `@pyqtSlot`, it must be `@pyqtSlot()`. On the other hand the window will never be shown since you do not call the `show()` method, and for the last one, the main error, is that you are evaluating the monitor function in the main thread, Worker needs you to pass the function without evaluating, and next to the arguments of that function, so you can invoke it within the secondary thread.

```
import sys
import os
import time
import traceback

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class SignalHelper(QObject):
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    finished = pyqtSignal()

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = SignalHelper()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value,  
                                    traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        path =  "Paths to watch"
        path2 = "Paths to watch"

        self.b = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.b.setCheckable(True)
        self.b.pressed.connect(lambda: self.watcher(path))

        self.b2 = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.b2.setCheckable(True)
        self.b2.pressed.connect(lambda: self.watcher(path2))

        layout.addWidget(self.b)
        layout.addWidget(self.b2)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

    def watcher(self, s):
        worker = Worker(self.monitor, s)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def monitor(self, s):
        before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(s)])
        while True:
            after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(s)])
            added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
            removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
            if added: print("Added: ", ", ".join(added))
            if removed: print("Deleted: ", ", ".join(removed))
            before = after

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```